# How to display accented words JSON on bash script with Python

Tags: python, json, bash, unix, character-encoding

I'm trying to display arrays with accent in the result but only arrays that don't have accent are showing.

Complete themoviedb API: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/566525?api_key=b2f8880475c888056b6207067fbaa197&language=pt-BR

```
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 28,
      "name": "Ação"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Aventura"
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "Fantasia"
    }
  ],

  "overview": "Shang-Chi precisa confrontar o passado que pensou ter deixado para trás. Ao mesmo tempo, ele é envolvido em uma teia de mistérios da organização conhecida como Dez Anéis.",
```

Shell code:

```
getMovieInfo()
{

  movieInfo=$(httpGet "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/566525?api_key=b2f8880475c888056b6207067fbaa197&append_to_response=videos&language=pt-BR")
  genreOne=$(echo "$movieInfo" | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['genres'][0]['name']" 2> /dev/null )
  genreTwo=$(echo "$movieInfo" | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['genres'][1]['name']" 2> /dev/null )
  genreThree=$(echo "$movieInfo" | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['genres'][2]['name']" 2> /dev/null )
  genres=$(echo "$genreOne $genreTwo $genreThree" | tr " " ",")
  overview=$(echo "$movieInfo" | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['overview']" 2> /dev/null )
}
```

**result:**

```
==========================================
| Title: Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings
| Language: en
| Genre: ,Aventura,Fantasia
| Runtime: 132 mins
| Overview:
==========================================
```

Comment: 1) you should probably use `jq` to parse your json instead of python 2) when you remove the `2> /dev/null `, are there any errors shown in the terminal ?

Comment: Please add desired output.

Comment: Also, is you shell configured to support [UTF-8 locales](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303712/how-can-i-enable-utf-8-support-in-the-linux-console) ?

Comment: @0stone0 I suppose they want something like `Genre: Ação,Aventura,Fantasia`. My guess would be that python is failing to parse lines containing UTF-8 characters

Comment: yes are showing "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 69: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: yes, i do my friend

Comment: Instead off using python, I'd recommend using [tag:jq]. Example: `curl <url> | jq '"\(.original_title) \(.genres | map(.name) | join(", "))"'` will show: `Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings Ação, Aventura, Fantasia`

Comment: I tested it and that's really what I was looking for! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a cleaner way to do this in jq. This solution also scales better (you don't need to know the number of elements in your array)

```
my_function() {
  movieInfo="$(httpGet "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/566525?api_key=b2f8880475c888056b6207067fbaa197&append_to_response=videos&language=pt-BR")"
  language="$(jq -r '.original_language' <<< $movieInfo)"
  genres="$(jq -r '[.genres[].name] | join(",")' <<< $movieInfo)"
  runtime="$(jq -r '.runtime' <<< $movieInfo)"
  overview="$(jq -r '.overview' <<< $movieInfo)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do all in Python.

For test I display also all keys in data - so I see what else I could display.

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/566525?api_key=b2f8880475c888056b6207067fbaa197&append_to_response=videos&language=pt-BR"

r = requests.get(url)

data = r.json()

print('keys:', data.keys())
print('---')

print('Title:', data['title'])
print('Language:', data['original_language'])
genres = ",".join(x['name'] for x in data['genres'])
print('Genres:', genres)
print('Runtime:', data['runtime'])
print('Overview:', data['overview'])
```

Result:

```
keys: ['adult', 'backdrop_path', 'belongs_to_collection', 'budget', 'genres', 'homepage', 'id', 'imdb_id', 'original_language', 'original_title', 'overview', 'popularity', 'poster_path', 'production_companies', 'production_countries', 'release_date', 'revenue', 'runtime', 'spoken_languages', 'status', 'tagline', 'title', 'video', 'vote_average', 'vote_count', 'videos']
---

Title: Shang-Chi e a Lenda dos Dez Anéis
Language: en
Genres: Ação,Aventura,Fantasia
Runtime: 132
Overview: Shang-Chi precisa confrontar o passado que pensou ter deixado para trás. Ao mesmo tempo, ele é envolvido em uma teia de mistérios da organização conhecida como Dez Anéis.
```

Tested on Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 20.04), Python 3.8

---

But problem can be if you use `Python 2` (it always had problem with encoding) or if your terminal can't display `UTF-8`. Python at start tries to recognize what encoding is used in terminal and it uses this encoding to display result. Sometimes problem is when data are `piped` to other program because it doesn't gives information what encoding uses `piping` and it automatically uses `ASCII` - and then you may have to use rather `sys.stdout.write()` and manually encode to `UTF-8` before writing.